# What is the difference between 'MultiJob phase' and 'Trigger/call builds on other project' in build step in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

I am wondering of significant differences between 'MultiJob phase' and 'Trigger/call builds on other project' in build step in Jenkins. Maybe somebody could also describe some situations where one approach would be better than other.

Answer (score 0):

You can call multiple jobs in both options.
In Trigger/call

1. Execute multiple jobs with comma separated.
2. All the jobs takes same parameters, and run in parallel.
3. You can either wait for job to finish or move on to next step.

In MultiJob Phase you get more configuration parameters. Some major options

1. You can call same/different jobs with different parameters.
2. You can run jobs in sequence or parallel.
3. You can run jobs based on condition.
4. Abort, retry and continue if fails.

You can refer the ? icon on Jenkins it provides definition of each parameter.